# como pasar parámetros a una consulta join desde swift a sqlite

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, programación-móvil

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    let campo1 : String = recibedatos.text!
    let campo2  = recibedatos_dos.text as! NSString
    let campo3 = campo2.utf8String

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,  "select \(campo1) from proveedores a left join  (select idproveedor from producosProveedores where idproducto = (select idproducto from producto where marca = ? ))  b  where a.idproveedor = b.idproveedor", -1, &statemet_consulta, nil) == SQLITE_OK
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statemet_consulta, 1 ,campo3, -1, nil)
            let numeroParametros = sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(statemet_consulta)
            print(numeroParametros);
            let nombreParametro = sqlite3_bind_parameter_name(statemet_consulta, 1)
            print(nombreParametro)


            let indiceparametro = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(statemet_consulta, campo3)
            print(indiceparametro)
        }
    else{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
            print("error preparing select: \(errmsg)")

        }



    while sqlite3_step(statemet_consulta) == SQLITE_ROW {
        let miusuario = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statemet_consulta, 0))
        print(miusuario)
        datosCamposProveedores.append(miusuario)
        print(usuario2)

    }
```

El problema es que al enviar el dato del parámetro esta consulta no me devuelve ninguna fila con lo cual el ciclo while no se ejecuta.

Sin embargo si sustituyo el parámetro por una valor constantes como 'libro' o entre comillas simples entonces el ciclo while se se ejecuta y devuelve la respuesta esperada.

Ya intente pasarle el valor de la variable directamente y tampoco lo hace. Alguien podría ayudarme

Comment: mírate este tutorial en ingles https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift

Answer (score 1):

Concatena el string en la consulta

```
"select" + campo1 + "....."
```